# Select footballers from two or more countries with SPARQL wikidata query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get the day of birth of all the footballers on wikipedia per country. Until now I've managed to get all the ones for one country, but I would like to get the ones on many countries at the same time, something like:

```
SELECT ?person ?dateOfBirth
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P1532 wd:Q16 OR ?person wdt:P1532 wd:Q141;
  wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Q16 is canada and Q141 is Argentina

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not limit your query to a single country, replace `wd:Q16` by a variable, i.e. `?person wdt:P1531 ?country`.

Then you need to restrict your query to football players.
This can be done with the following line

```
?person wdt:P106 wd:Q937857.
```

And probably you want the names of the players, not only der ID. Thus, add `?personLabel` after "select".

Combined, the query reads

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?country ?countryLabel ?dateOfBirth
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P106 wd:Q937857;
          wdt:P1532 ?country;          
          wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a perfect answer